# как сделать чтобы в конце теста он подсчитал кол-во правильных ответов?

Tags: javascript

```js
var a = parseInt(prompt("2+2?"));
switch (a) {
  case 4:
    alert("правильно");
    break;
  default:
    alert("неправильно")
}
var b = parseInt(prompt("5+5?"));
switch (b) {
  case 10:
    alert("правильно");
    break;
  default:
    alert("неправильно")
}
var c = parseInt(prompt("3+12?"));
switch (c) {
  case 15:
    alert("правильно")
    break;
  default:
    alert("неправильно")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let good = bad = 0;

var a = parseInt(prompt("2+2?"));
switch (a) {
  case 4:
    alert("правильно");
    good++;
    break;
  default:
    alert("неправильно")
    bad++;
}
var b = parseInt(prompt("5+5?"));
switch (b) {
  case 10:
    alert("правильно");
    good++;
    break;
  default:
    alert("неправильно")
    bad++;
}
var c = parseInt(prompt("3+12?"));
switch (c) {
  case 15:
    alert("правильно")
    good++;
    break;
  default:
    alert("неправильно")
    bad++;
}


console.info(good === 0 ? `Все ответы (${bad}) ложные` : bad === 0 ? `Вы ответили верно на все (${good}) вопросы` : `Правильных ${good}, ложных ${bad}`);
```

Comment: Спасибо тут выражают в плюсе к репутации. И если ответ Вас устроил, жмите принять (галочка слева от ответа).

Answer (score 0):

записывайте в переменную количество правильных ответов

```
var right = 0;
......
case 4: 
alert("правильно"); 
right  = right  + 1;
break;
```

Comment: спасибо,а как в конце вывести общее кол-во?Если не сложно,написать концовку на моем примере!??